# how to request a subdirectory http GET request networking

Tags: http, networking, get, request

I'm trying to fetch a subdirectory using a get request.

What I've tried (for `mysite.com/search`):

```
char message[] = "GET / \r\nHost:mysite.com/search\r\n\n\n";
```

This however is giving me a 400 error (bad request)

How do I correctly request a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Host` only accepts the base url/ip. See that / right after the GET? That's where you request any subdirectories/files you want. The / you have there now indicates that you want the top level dictionary.

What you are looking for is:

```
char message[] = "GET /search \r\nHost:mysite.com\r\n\n\n";
```